# Pandas finding a text in row and assign a dummy variable value based on this

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a data frame which contains a text column i.e. `df["input"]`,

I would like to create a new variable which checks whether `df["input"]` column contains any of the word in a given list and assigns a value of 1 if previous dummy variable is equal to 0 (logic is 1) create a dummy variable that equals to zero 2) replace it to one if it contains any word in a given list and it was not contained in the previous lists.)

```
# Example lists
listings = ["amazon listing", "ecommerce", "products"]
scripting = ["subtitle",  "film", "dubbing"]
medical = ["medical", "biotechnology", "dentist"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'input': ['amazon listing subtitle', 
                             'medical', 
                             'film biotechnology dentist']})
```

which looks like:

```
input
amazon listing subtitle
medical 
film biotechnology dentist
```

final dataset should look like:

```
input                           listings  scripting  medical
amazon listing subtitle            1         0         0
medical                            0         0         1          
film biotechnology dentist         0         1         0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible implementation is to use `str.contains` in a loop to create the 3 columns, then use `idxmax` to get the column name (or the list name) of the first match, then create a dummy variable from these matches:

```
import numpy as np
d = {'listings':listings, 'scripting':scripting, 'medical':medical}
for k,v in d.items():
    df[k] = df['input'].str.contains('|'.join(v))

arr = df[list(d)].to_numpy()
tmp = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype='int8')
tmp[np.arange(len(arr)), arr.argmax(axis=1)] = arr.max(axis=1)
out = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=list(d)).combine_first(df)
```

But in this case, it might be more efficient to use a nested for-loop:

```
import re
def get_dummy_vars(col, lsts):
    out = []
    len_lsts = len(lsts)
    for row in col:
        tmp = []
        # in the nested loop, we use the any function to check for the first match 
        # if there's a match, break the loop and pad 0s since we don't care if there's another match
        for lst in lsts:
            tmp.append(int(any(True for x in lst if re.search(fr"\b{x}\b", row))))
            if tmp[-1]:
                break
        tmp += [0] * (len_lsts - len(tmp))
        out.append(tmp)
    return out

lsts = [listings, scripting, medical]
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(get_dummy_vars(df['input'], lsts), columns=['listings', 'scripting', 'medical']))
```

Output:

```
                        input listings medical scripting
0     amazon listing subtitle        1       0         0
1                     medical        0       1         0
2  film biotechnology dentist        0       0         1
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the following error:       7         # if there's a match, break the loop and pad 0s since we don't care if there's another match
      8         for lst in lsts:
----> 9             tmp.append(int(any(True for x in lst if x in row)))
     10             if tmp[-1]:
     11                 break

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: @edyvedy13 it seems you have NaN values in this column. Check with `df['input'].isna().sum()`. One way is to drop these rows. But it’s up to you how you want to handle them.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the second code does not work:

Comment: I changed the scripting = ["subtitle",  "subtitle",  "film",  "script",  "script",  "script",  "documentary",  "documentary","video",  "video",   "youtube",  "youtube",  "subtitling",  "subtitling",  "cartoon",  "cartoon",  "movie",  "movie",  "sub. tran.",  "sub. tran.",  "sub translation",  "sub translation"] and input to dx = pd.DataFrame({'input': [' supreme pillow - job description', 
                             'medical', 
                             'film biotechnology dentist']})

Comment: There is no match for the scripting but the dummy variable takes the value of one

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want code to match exact words

Comment: @edyvedy13 the function can be changed rather easily using python-re module. I edited the answer. It should work now. The pandas answer needs a little finagling. I'll correct in a bit. Sorry.

Comment: @edyvedy13 I edited the first method as well. Now both should work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler - more pandas vector style solution:

```
patterns = {} #<-- dictionary
patterns["listings"] = ["amazon listing", "ecommerce", "products"]
patterns["scripting"] = ["subtitle",  "film", "dubbing"]
patterns["medical"] = ["medical", "biotechnology", "dentist"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'input': ['amazon listing subtitle', 
                             'medical', 
                             'film biotechnology dentist']})
#---------------------------------------------------------------#

# step 1, for each column create a reg-expression
for col, items in patterns.items():
    
    # create a regex pattern (word1|word2|word3)
    pattern = f"({'|'.join(items)})"
    
    # find the pattern in the input column
    df[col] = df['input'].str.contains(pattern, regex=True).astype(int)
    
# step 2, if the value to the left is 1, change its value to 0

## 2.1 create a mask
## shift the rows to the right, 
## --> if the left column contains the same value as the current column: True, otherwise False
mask = (df == df.shift(axis=1)).values

# substract the mask from the df 
## and clip the result --> negative values will become 0
df.iloc[:,1:] = np.clip( df[mask].iloc[:,1:] - mask[:,1:], 0, 1 )

print(df)
```

Result

```
                        input  listings  scripting  medical
0     amazon listing subtitle         1          0        0
1                     medical         0          0        1
2  film biotechnology dentist         0          1        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question and good answers (I somehow missed it yesterday)! Here's another variation with [`.str.extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
search = {"listings": listings, "scripting": scripting, "medical": medical, "dummy": []}
pattern = "|".join(
    f"(?P<{column}>" + "|".join(r"\b" + s + r"\b" for s in strings) + ")"
    for column, strings in search.items()
)
result = (
    df["input"].str.extractall(pattern).assign(dummy=True).groupby(level=0).any()
               .idxmax(axis=1).str.get_dummies().drop(columns="dummy")
)
```